# Using std::swap_ranges with std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, swap

I would like to swap parts of two maps using a standard algorithm, but somehow iterators on map do not seem to be swappable. I am surely missing something.

## Example

```
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>

auto function(std::map<int,int> m1, std::map<int,int> m2)
{
    auto first = m1.begin();
    auto last = first;
    std::advance(last, 3);
    std::swap_ranges(first, last, m2.begin());
}
```

## Error

See it on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/6bn1xYTTr

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/map:60,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = _Rb_tree_iterator<pair<const int, int> >; _ForwardIterator2 = _Rb_tree_iterator<pair<const int, int> >]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:212:16:   required from '_ForwardIterator2 std::swap_ranges(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = _Rb_tree_iterator<pair<const int, int> >; _ForwardIterator2 = _Rb_tree_iterator<pair<const int, int> >]'
<source>:9:21:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:182:11: error: use of deleted function 'typename std::enable_if<(! std::__and_<std::__is_swappable<_T1>, std::__is_swappable<_T2> >::value)>::type std::swap(pair<_T1, _T2>&, pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = int; typename enable_if<(! __and_<__is_swappable<_T1>, __is_swappable<_T2> >::value)>::type = void]'
  182 |       swap(*__a, *__b);
      |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:715:5: note: declared here
  715 |     swap(pair<_T1, _T2>&, pair<_T1, _T2>&) = delete;
      |     ^~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: As a map has to be in order, it does not make sense to allows that operation in general. Let sya you have `1 3 5` and `2 6 8` and you swap from the second item up to third item not include, you would then have `1 6 5` and `2 3 8`. The first map would be corrupted (items in wrong order). You need to use a temporary container where you pur removed item from first map and then move items from the second map to the first one and finally add item from the temporary map to the second one.

Comment: Oh I see. It is a generalization problem in case of mismatching keys. So I guess I will have to do a manual for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map` is implemented as some sort of binary search tree, and its structure depends on each item's key never changing.  Thus the type returned by `*m1.begin()` is `std::pair<const int, int>&`.  Note that the first `int` is `const`.  You cannot modify it.

`std::swap_ranges` tries to swap each element of the first range with its corresponding element in the second range, but `std::pair<const int, int>`s can't be `swap`ped due to the `const`ness of their first element.

Comment: I see. It is counter-intuitive though, as I expect to be able to swap a range in a map regardless of the implementation detail. Is there a satisfying way around?

Comment: What do you expect the result of swapping the ranges to be?  Should the corresponding to each key be swapped?

Comment: oh, I see your point. The behavior would be unclear in case of keys in m1 missing in m2? Well in my case that actually does not matter, as the guarantee exists that the keys are the same, and in that case I would indeed just need to swap the value of each key.